# Change textbox input

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I want to allow the user to enter symbols using the keyboard. I'm checking the textbox onkeydown event for the pressed key and then change it to a symbol, for example if I would press 'a' then the textbox would show '☺'. But the problem is that the textbox shows both 'a' and '☺'. Is there a better event to check this, or better way to do this?

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(sender as object, e as keyeventargs) handles TextBox.KeyDown
  Select Case e.key
    Case 'a'
      TextBox.text += '☺'
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Paste the exact code which transforms textbox text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the `KeyPress` event. In that event handler, you'll want to set the `Handled` property of the `KeyPressEventArgs` to true to keep the `a` key from getting added to the textbox.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(sender as object, e as KeyPressEventArgs) handles TextBox.KeyPress
  Select Case e.key
    Case 'a'
      TextBox.text += '☺'
      e.Handled = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Return false from the onKeyDown handler function and it should prevent the 'a' being added.